# MySQL - query - multiple group by

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following table, in which I'm trying to SUM if type = 'printer', however, I would like not to count repeat client_ids. So I expect something like this:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
| k_id | client_id | type      |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 |       100 | pc        | 
|    2 |       101 | printer   | 
|    3 |       101 | printer   | 
|    4 |       101 | printer   | 
|    5 |       102 | cellphone | 
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

Query:

```
  SELECT client_id, 
         SUM(IF(type = 'printer', 1,0)) 
    FROM FOO 
GROUP BY type, client_id;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+
| client_id | SUM(IF(type = 'printer', 1,0)) |
+-----------+--------------------------------+
|       102 |                              0 | 
|       100 |                              0 | 
|       101 |                              3 | 
+-----------+--------------------------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+
| client_id | SUM(IF(type = 'printer', 1,0)) |
+-----------+--------------------------------+
|       102 |                              0 | 
|       100 |                              0 | 
|       101 |                              1 | 
+-----------+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three rows with a type of `printer`.  `Sum` adds them all up, and returns 3.

If you'd like to see `1` for rows with printers, and `0` otherwise, try `max` instead of `sum`:

```
MAX(IF(type = 'printer', 1,0))
^^^
```

EDIT: To count the number of distinct printers, you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT  client_id
,       (
        select  count(*) 
        from    FOO as f2 
        where   f1.client_id = f2.client_id
                and type = 'Printer'
        )
FROM    FOO as f1
GROUP BY 
        client_id
```

Comment: in mysql you dont need max, just omit the function

Comment: @Josh: You could use a subquery (added to answer)   @Imre L: Without `max()`, it would run the `if` only for a random row, not all if them

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
   SELECT x.client_id,
          COUNT(DISTINCT y.type) 
     FROM FOO x
LEFT JOIN FOO y ON y.client_id = x.client_id
               AND y.type = 'printer'
 GROUP BY x.client
```

If you don't need to see the rows with zero counts:

```
   SELECT client_id, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT type)
     FROM FOO 
    WHERE type = 'printer'
 GROUP BY type, client_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT client_id, if( `type` = 'printer', 1, 0 )
FROM foo
GROUP BY TYPE , client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct client_id, 
     (IF(type = 'printer', 1,0)) 
FROM FOO
```

(I'm guessing: I'm not aquainted with IF(..))